# javascript clearing text fields, how to insert values with powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, webforms

I'm trying to automate filling out a form for the workplace and I thought powershell would be a great tool to use for this so I decided what better time to learn.

The script allows you to select an excel file, converts this to a csv file and then runs through each record in the CSV putting them into the corresponding fields in the form.
The form has a javascript autocomplete function that fills in fields while you type, for example if you'd type "la" it will autofill with "laptop" and have the option for "lan switch" as well, characters other than "p" or "n" won't be accepted. The problem I'm running into is that even when I insert the correct string ("laptop") into the corresponding field it will clear the field once I (or the script) press the save button.

I was thinking maybe sending the actual keystrokes instead of putting in the string could fix this issue but I couldn't figure out how to send keystrokes to the fields, only how to send a general keystroke to IE.

After checking the network tab in chrome developer tools I've found out what the javascript actually does: first it clears the input field, and adds items to it (what it guesses your input might be), gives you an "exact guess" which it shows in the input field.

After looking at the code a bit more I'm fairly certain the script autofills based on keypresses so if I could trigger the necessary keypresses it should work.

My code here:

```
try
{
    Get-Date

    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

    Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
        {
            [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

            $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
            $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
            $OpenFileDialog.filter = "xlsx (*.xlsx)| *.xlsx|xls (*.xls)| *.xls|XLSX (*.XLSX)| *.XLSX|XLS (*.XLS)| *.XLS"
            $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
            $OpenFileDialog.filename
        }

    Function Set-SaveFile()
        {
            [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

            $SaveFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
            $SaveFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
            $SaveFileDialog.filter = "csv (*.csv)| *.csv"
            $SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
            $SaveFileDialog.filename
        }

    $inputfile = Get-FileName "C:\temp"
    $input = $inputfile

    If($input -ne "")
        {
            $ExcelBestand = $Input
            $SavePath = Set-SaveFile
            $ExcelObject = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
            $SheetObject = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($ExcelBestand)
            $SheetObject.Saveas($SavePath, 6)
            $SheetObject.Close($false)
            $ExcelObject.Quit()

            $CSVfile = Import-Csv -Path $SavePath -Delimiter ";"

            ForEach ($CSVrecord in $CSVfile)
                { 
                    $Objectid = $($CSVrecord.Labelnummer)
                    $seriestring = "Serienummer (Imei)"
                    $Serienummer = $($CSVrecord.$seriestring)
                    $macstring = "MAC adres (SIM)"
                    $MAC = $($CSVrecord.$macstring)
                    $Merk = $($CSVrecord.Merk)
                    $Productnaam = $($CSVrecord.Productnaam)
                    $Leverdatum = $($CSVrecord.Leverdatum)
                    $UUID = $($CSVrecord.UUID)
                    $leverdatum =$($CSVrecord.Leverdatum)
                    $zendingsa = "Zending SA" 
                    $POnummer = "PO nummer"
                    $adresgegevens = $("Afleveradres: " + $CSVrecord.Afleveradres + "`r`n") +
                        $("Huisnummer: " + $CSVrecord.Huisnummer + "`r`n") + 
                        $("Toevoeging: " + $CSVrecord.Toevoeging + "`r`n") + 
                        $("Plaats: " + $CSVrecord.Plaats + "`r`n") + 
                        $("Medewerker: " + $CSVrecord.Medewerker + "`r`n") + 
                        $("Zending SA: " + $CSVrecord.$zendingsa + "`r`n") + 
                        $("PO Nummer: " + $CSVrecord.$POnummer + "`r`n")

                    $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application

                    $IE.navigate2("url")
                    while($ie.busy) {start-sleep -Milliseconds 200}

                    $IE.visible=$true

                    $ie.document.getElementById("naam").value = $Objectid

                    if ($Objectid -match "LAP")
                        {
                            $ie.document.getElementById("soortid").value = "Laptop"
                        }
                    elseif ($Objectid -match "DSK")
                        {
                            $ie.document.getElementById("soortid").value = "Desktop"
                        }
                    elseif ($Objectid -match "PRN")
                        {
                            $ie.document.getElementById("soortid").value = "Printer"
                        }
                    elseif ($Objectid -match "MON")
                        {
                            $ie.document.getElementById("soortid").value = "Monitor"
                        }

                    $ie.document.getElementById("merkid").value = $Merk

                    $ie.document.getElementById("objecttypeid").value = $Productnaam

                    $ie.document.getElementById("serienummer").value = $Serienummer

                    $ie.document.getElementById("macadres").value = $MAC

                    $ie.document.getElementById("leverancierid").value = "SA (Support)"

                    $ie.document.getElementById("vestigingid").value = "MM25"

                    $ie.document.getElementById("statusid").value = "Voorraad"

                    $IE.document.getElementById("tab.record_notes").style.display = "block"

                    $IE.document.getElementById("aantekeningen").value = "Leverdatum: " + $Leverdatum + "`r`n" + "UUID: " + $UUID + "`r`n" + $adresgegevens

                    $ie.document.getElementById("save").click()
                    #$IE.Quit()
                }

            $DeleteAnswer = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Delete Csv file?", "YesNo,SystemModal,Exclamation", "Delete")
            if($DeleteAnswer -eq 'Yes')
                {
                    Remove-Item $SavePath -confirm
                }
            [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Success", "OKOnly,SystemModal,Information", "Success")
        }

    elseif($input -eq "")
        {
            [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("Cancelled.", "OkOnly,SystemModal,Critical", "Cancelled")
        }

    $CurrentDateTime = get-date -format "dd-MM-yyyy HHmm"
    $Log = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.ConsolePane.text
    $ConseoleOutputPath = "C:\ConsoleOutput "
    $Extension = ".txt"
    set-content -path $ConsoleOutputPath$CurrentDatetime$Extension $log
    $Log
    Exit
}
catch
{
    $CurrentDateTime = get-date -format "dd-MM-yyyy HHmm"
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("error.", "OkOnly,SystemModal,Critical", "error")
    $Log = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.ConsolePane.text
    $ErrorLogPath = "C:\ErrorLog "
    $Extension = ".txt"
    set-content -path $ErrorLogPath$CurrentDatetime$Extension $log
    $Log
    Exit
}
```

The javascript functions that clears the text field here:

```
function clearList(textboxID)
{
var t = document.getElementById(textboxID);
if (t) 
{
    select = document.getElementById("myselect");
    if (select.textbox && t == select.textbox)
    {
        while (select.options.length > 0)
        {
            select.remove(0);
        }
    }
    t.optionsList = new Array();
    t.optionIndex = -1;
    t.optionsListUnselected = "";
}
}
```

Am I correct in thinking triggering the keypresses would work, if not is there a different/better way?
Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out on how to trigger keypresses inside of text fields.

Comment: If you need to do website automation, I would suggest looking into using Selenium, it is open source and available on Git (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), it has a lot of behind the sceens features that will do most of the work for you. To clear a text field in javascript you just need to set it's value property to empty string,if all you want is to set it's value, just set element.value equal to new value, there is a nuget package library I use for reading data from excel called ExcelDataReader, can be imported into Visual studio using the package manager. Good luck

Comment: Hey @RyanWilson

I think you misread regarding the second part of your comment, I'm not looking to empty a string with javascript, quite the opposite - there is a javascript function in place that does that, which causes the strings I insert to dissapear once I try to click the save button.

Comment: Also regarding your point on using Selenium, the reason I chose for powershell is because it's available on all the PCs here, rolling out Selenium would be an impossible task.